# Conditional Join depending on field value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on creating the database structure for my company's new system. Our web based application links several of our internal applications together.

Inside of our database, I have an HR schema that contains a series of tables housing the data for all our company's employees. However, we are also going to have two other companies with access to our systems.

Now in the employee schema, I have some of the following tables:

```
employees (houses name, address, etc)
phone_manager (houses multiple phone numbers for each employee, mobile, home, etc.)
email_manager (again multiple emails per employee)
```

among others, but these are the primary contain tables.

For the other companies, there is a single table, this table houses the name, phone number, email, and company for each of their employees.

My main question is how would I build a relationship between these tables and my users table to be able to enumerate all useful information for all the different users?

Example of output for data table containing all users

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Name        ║ Work Number  ║ Mobile Number ║ Email 1      ║ Email 2      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ John Doe    ║ 111-555-0123 ║ 123-456-7890  ║ j.d@hp.com   ║ johnd@hp.com ║
║ Jane Doe    ║ 121-545-0123 ║               ║ janed@hp.com ║              ║
║ Michael Joe ║              ║ 123-987-4567  ║              ║ mj@cc.net    ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╝
```

There will also be a column for company, which is derived from a table called organizations.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for database design. Check this link if this schema make sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066846/how-do-i-use-pivot-on-this-data/23067210#23067210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT employees.Name,
       phone_manager.Work_Number AS 'Work Number', 
       phone_manager.Mobile_Number AS 'Mobile Number',
       email_manager.Email_1 AS 'Email 1',
       email_manager.Email_2 AS 'Email 2'
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN phone_manager ON phone_manager.employee_id = employees.id
LEFT JOIN email_manager ON email_manager.employee_id = employees.id
```

**EDIT** To answer the question in your comment, add the following condition to the end of the query:

```
WHERE employees.id IN(SELECT users.employee_id FROM users
                      WHERE users.company_id IN(1, 2))
```

Alternatively, you can add the users table using `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT employees.Name,
       phone_manager.Work_Number AS 'Work Number', 
       phone_manager.Mobile_Number AS 'Mobile Number',
       email_manager.Email_1 AS 'Email 1',
       email_manager.Email_2 AS 'Email 2'
FROM employees
INNER JOIN users ON users.employee_id = employees.id AND users.company_id IN(1, 2)
LEFT JOIN phone_manager ON phone_manager.employee_id = employees.id
LEFT JOIN email_manager ON email_manager.employee_id = employees.id
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine for grabbing our employees. But let's say, for example, in my Users table, I have two fields: employee_id, company_id. If company id=1 or id=2, then we need to grab their emails, names, phone number, etc from the organization_employees table.

Comment: That seems like a definite step in the right direction. The problem is going to be that the schema for my employees table and the schema for the other companies' employees are wildly different. My employees can have many many emails, so I'll have to select all of them, the same with the phone numbers. These emails and numbers are all stored in separate tables.

However, with the other companies, I single table houses 2 numbers and 1 email, and the employee's information. So the query to get their information is different. I should be able to chain together two select statements and union them

Comment: @Jdsfighter that is correct, you can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a key in the Employees table that can uniquely identify an employee like an auto incrementing number or any other one you choose to be.

You can use that EmpID in other tables like phone manager / email manager if you need.

Remember, A manager is also an employee so the manager id also can be derived from the Employee table only, you don't need to create any new one for that.

Take a quick look at the Adventure works database and that give you more insight on this.

Comment: The employee table only handles my own company's employee information. There is a separate table that handles the information for the other companies' employees. I need to determine how to grab information from one table if the ID is 0, and grab it from a different table if it is > 0.

Comment: you can use a Case statement or an IF statement as it permits. you can do a regular join but pull different columns using CASE.